# Transpose a 2D array

Tags: c, performance, algorithm, embedded, matrix

How do you efficiently transpose a matrix?  Are there libraries for this, or what algorithm would you use?

E.g.:

```
short src[W*H] = {
  {1,2,3},
  {4,5,6}
};
short dest[W*H];


rotate_90_clockwise(dest,src,W,H); //<-- magic in here, no need for in-place

//dest is now:

{
  {4, 1},
  {5, 2},
  {6, 3}
};
```

(In my specific case its src array is raw image data, and the destination is a framebuffer, and I'm embedded on ARM on a toolchain that doesn't support assembly)

Comment: Could that be homework ?  ;-)

Comment: That's not actually a usual matrix transposition - the transpose maps `(row, col)` to `(col, row)`.

Comment: It wuold help a tiny bit to kow what you're embedding it no aswell. smoething with access to a GPU could just use their dot-product operations easily, for instance.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

There are libraries for this, in some cases.  And, notably, there are tricks you can play with vectorized data (e.g., four 32-bit elements in a 128-bit vector, but this also applies to four 8-bit bytes in a 32-bit register) to go faster than individual-element accesses.

For a transpose, the standard idea is that you use "shuffle" instructions, which allow you to create a new data vector out of two existing vectors, in any order.  You work with 4x4 blocks of the input array.  So, starting out, you have:

```
v0 = 1 2 3 4
v1 = 5 6 7 8
v2 = 9 A B C
v3 = D E F 0
```

Then, you apply shuffle instructions to the first two vectors (interleaving their odd elements, A0B0 C0D0 -> ABCD, and interleaving their even elements, 0A0B 0C0D -> ABCD), and to the last two, to create a new set of vectors with each 2x2 block transposed:

```
1 5 3 7
2 6 4 8
9 D B F
A E C 0
```

Finally, you apply shuffle instructions to the odd pair and the even pair (combining their first pairs of elements, AB00 CD00 -> ABCD, and their last pairs, 00AB 00CD -> ABCD), to get:

```
1 5 9 D
2 6 A E
3 7 B F
4 8 C 0
```

And there, 16 elements transposed in eight instructions!

Now, for 8-bit bytes in 32-bit registers, ARM doesn't have exactly shuffle instructions, but you can synthesize what you need with shifts and a SEL (select) instruction, and the second set of shuffles you can do in one instruction with the PKHBT (pack halfword bottom top) and PKHTB (pack halfword top bottom) instructions.

Finally, if you're using a large ARM processor with NEON vectorizations, you can do something like this with 16-element vectors on 16x16 blocks.

Comment: This is a proper matrix transpose (row 1 becomes column 1), the example given in the question is a matrix rotation (row 1 becomes column 2).

Answer (score 19):

One very simple solution that works in O(1) is saving an additional boolean for the matrix, saying whether it is 'transposed' or not. 
Then accessing the array will be made according to this boolean (row/col or col/row).

Of course, it will impede your cache utilization.

So if you have many transpose operations, and few "complete traversals" (which, btw, might also be re-ordered according to the value of the boolean), this is your best choice.

Comment: I'm going to upvote this as a damn good thinking-outside-the-box solution. Provided you access your matrices via an API rather than directly, you could quite easily have a structure with a transposed flag and the actual data and use the transposed flag to return width and height as well as swap them for getters and setters.

Comment: Alternatively, if you want to avoid all the cache issues people are talking about, just keep both normal and transposed copies in memory at the same time (the setter API can ensure they never get out of step). Probably no good for this specific case (since it's embedded) but may be worth it for regular systems.

Comment: Its thinking outside the box, but it isn't rotating a landscape image to display it on a portrait-memory screen.

Comment: This just postpones the problem, but of course that may be just what you need!

Comment: *"Its thinking outside the box, but it isn't rotating a landscape image to display it on a portrait-memory screen"* If that is what you wanted you should have asked for it. Because the question you asked is *not* how to rotate an image.

Comment: I should be more specific - this isn't a way of efficiently transposing/rotating/whatever a matrix, its a way of avoiding doing so in return for a performance penalty when actually doing so.

Comment: Will, it really depends on what you want to do with your matrix. In your case, you need to pass it to the screen (I'm not very familiar with images/putting stuff on the screen), so this method might not be a panacea here. 
In other cases, what you'll need to do is multiply the matrix, or access it (read from it) when it is transposed. Or maybe find a sub-matrix etc. 
For the above examples you do need the transposed matrix (conceptually). You can avoid "actually transposing" it altogether using the method above.

Comment: Anna, if you want to efficiently transpose a matrix then you want to actually do it, and efficiently at that.  The matrix has a natural order in memory and accessing it out-of-order is extremely expensive.  Simply saying 'please go the slow way' is not really a good out of the box thinking for a question tagged performance and using the word 'efficient' in the first sentence!

Comment: Well, we are repeating ourselves. Many things that are presented in a one way to the user can be done completely differently behind the scenes, so I'm not accepting your claim about "actually doing it", although it might be necessary in the case of the picture. Your claim about it being slow is simply wrong. You are changing a boolean, it is very fast :). Later, when you'll need to access the matrix, many of the things can be done in the order you wish. For example, if you need to do copy sub parts of the matrix, or change cells, you are just saving lots of time for the initial transpose.

Comment: Ha! 600 characters is not always enough! I feel like writing an SMS :-)

Answer (score 4):

Wikipedia has an [entire article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/In-place_matrix_transposition) on in-place matrix transposition.  For non-square matrices, it's a non-trivial, fairly interesting problem (while using less than O(N x M) memory, that is).  The article has links to quite a few papers with algorithms, as well as some source code.

Watch out though - as I said in a comment to your question, your demonstration is *not* of a standard transposition, which all of the algorithms will be written for.

(A standard transposition function will give this result for your example data:)

```
{
  {1, 4},
  {2, 5},
  {3, 6}
};
```

If you're just doing this to display an image on a screen, you may be best off just doing the transposition as you copy the image to the back buffer, rather than transposing in-place and then blitting.

Answer (score 3):

- If matrix is square or if you are not looking for an inplace transposition it's really easy:

Basically you iterate on lines and swap every items with matching column items. You get the matching item by exchanging row and column indexes. When you've treated all columns transposition is finished. You can also go the other way around and iterate on columns.

If you want to increase performance you can copy a full line into a temporary array and the full matching column into another, then copy them back. It should be slightly faster (even if this strategy involve one more variable assignment) if you use a memcopy for transfers involving innermost elements.

- If matrix is not square (as in your example) it's really tricky to do it inplace. As transposing doesn't change memory needs it still looks possible to do it inplace, but if you do it carelessly you will end up overwriting elements of another line or column.

If memory is not a bottleneck I recommand using a temporary matrix. It's really easier and it will probably be faster anyway.

- The best method is not transposing at all but just setting a flag somewhere stating if you access data row-first or column-first. In most cases algorithms that need transpositions can be rewritten to access to a not transposed matrix as if it were. To achieve this you just have to rewrite some basic operations like matrix products to accept matrixes with one orientation or the other.

But in some cases i understand this will not be possible, typically if data is being prepared for being accessed by some existing hardware or library.

Answer (score 1):

The most efficent solution here is to rotate the data as it is being copied from RAM to the framebuffer. Rotating the source in RAM and then copying the result to the framebuffer will be, at best, half the speed of the copy-and-rotate version. So, the question is, is it more efficient to read sequentially and write randomly or read randomly and write sequentially. In code, this would be the choice between:

```
// read sequential
src = { image data }
dest = framebuffer
for (y = 0 ; y < H ; ++y)
{
   for (x = 0 ; x < W ; ++x)
   {
     pixel = *src++
     dest [y,x] = pixel
   }
}
```

or:

```
// write sequential
src = { image data }
dest = framebuffer
for (x = 0 ; x < W ; ++x)
{
   for (y = 0 ; y < H ; ++y)
   {
     pixel = src [x,y]
     *dest++ = pixel
   }
}
```

The answer to this can only be determined by profiling the code.

Now, it may be that you have a GPU in which case it would certainly have the ability to do rotations and it will be far more efficient to let the GPU do the rotation when blitting the image to the screen.

Comment: this was my own starting point, but I've been experimenting with having 'cursors' on several scanlines at once, the assumption being that there will be less cache misses.

Answer (score 0):

Just a simple copy to temp and copy-back, transposing as you go, using pointer-stepping to avoid the multiply in address calculation, and the inner loop unrolled:

```
char temp[W*H];
char* ptemp = temp;
memcpy(temp, array, sizeof(char)*W*H);
for (i = 0; i < H; i++){
    char* parray = &array[i];
    for (j = 0; j+8 <= W; j += 8, ptemp += 8){
        *parray = ptemp[0]; parray += H;
        *parray = ptemp[1]; parray += H;
        *parray = ptemp[2]; parray += H;
        *parray = ptemp[3]; parray += H;
        *parray = ptemp[4]; parray += H;
        *parray = ptemp[5]; parray += H;
        *parray = ptemp[6]; parray += H;
        *parray = ptemp[7]; parray += H;
    }
    for (; j < W; j++, parray += H){
        *parray = *ptemp++;
    }
}
```

I don't know how to avoid the cache-locality issue because of the nature of the problem.