# Looking for the fastest algorithm (implementing in C) for image manipulation

Tags: c, algorithm, image

I have a square matrix (n*n) of chars, and i want to flip the image.

I'm looking to do it in the fastest time possible (don't mind the ram at all at the moment).

The obvious choice will be  to just copy the matrix line by line, but i think there is a better way.
ideas?

Comment: Define "flip", please. This could mean transpose (if it's a matrix). Or to some, rotate. Is it stored as a single array, or an array of pointers to arrays? How are pixels represented? (One char = one pixel?)

Comment: Actually i had to find a solution to several transpositions: creating a vertical mirror, an horizontal mirror and both, so it didn't really matter. One char represents one pixel, and the matrix was stored as one array.

Answer (score 4):

Flipping vertically is pretty easy to do fast: Just allocate an extra temp line and use `memcpy` to swap entire lines at a time between the top and bottom of the image/matrix.

Flipping horizontally is hard to speed up unless you want to write assembly, and the optimal solution is going to be very cpu-dependent.

Answer (score 2):

**Solution 1 - Swap Pointers**

Depending on the representation of the data (and assuming each character represents a "pixel"_, it could potentially be accomplished just by swapping pointers around.  For example, if it is defined as:

```
char *matrix[N];
```

Where each "row" (or "column" depending on the definition) is then dynamically allocated, you could swap pointers.  Do this (but in a loop ... I'm just showing the idea of a single swap):

```
char* tmp = matrix[0];
matrix[0] = matrix[N-1];
matrix[N-1] = tmp;
```

Depending on the layout, the representation could be rows or columns.

**Solution 2 - Don't Move/Swap Anything**

Depending on how the data is rendered, the fastest method might not be to flip the data at all.  Just display it in a different order.  For example, instead of this:

```
for ( r = 0; r < N; r++ )
   for ( c = 0; c < N; c++ )
      displayMe( r, c, matrix[r][c] );
```

Do this (or something like it):

```
for ( r = 0; r < N; r++ )
   for ( c = 0; c < N; c++ )
      displayMe( r, c, matrix[N - r - 1][c] );
```

Comment: Instead of having the subtractions in the indexation, reverse the loop.

Comment: @NiklasHansson:  That is a possibility, however, I think that then the display location (the first two params in my invented `displayMe` function) would need a subtraction.  Either the location or the matrix index needs to be "inverted".

Comment: Inverted = switch places? True. The gain is the lesser amount of subtractions.

Comment: An improvement to solution 2: don't even use a different loop. Instead, have a variable called `stride` which is the difference between pointers to line `N+1` and line `N`. Use negative stride and a pointer to the last line to treat the image as upside-down. This is the approach `mplayer` uses, and it makes it so all video filter code can process upside-down-flipped images just as easily as "normal" ones without any expensive conversion steps.

Comment: Nice one, @R.., You should add that to your answer.

Comment: @R.. Seconded -- simply using a negative stride/end pointer to traverse scanlines in reverse is an awesome trick, and would make your existing answer even better.

Answer (score 0):

If what you are actually looking for is a matrix transpose (rotation of 90 degrees) look at [Transpose a 2D array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1453033/transpose-a-2d-array)

Answer (score 0):

If you are going to walk through all your matrix, it's highly recommended to use an unidimensional array to represent your matrix because nested fors are very expensive.